# Can I get a value returned from a $.Deferred() that can be used in the display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using the `$.Deferred` method to try and get a function to load some Json, work on the results, then pass the value back to another function that will use the result (in this case I expect an integer). For some reason I can get this integer displayed using either `alert` or `console.log` functions, but when it comes to using it as the return value of the actual function the code falls over and returns `undefined`.

For reference here's my code:

```
function NewValue(){
      var dataPromise = GetDataFromJson();
      dataPromise.done(function(data){
      //note both console.log(data) and alert(data) deliver the correct result here
        return data;
      });
    }

    function GetDataFromJson() {
      var jsonData;
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
    d3.json("http://localhost:8000/pipeline.json", function(dataFromServer){
          jsonData = dataFromServer;
          headers = ["Won"];
          myTotal = 0;
          chunks = (headers.map(function(priceRange) {
              return jsonData.map(function(d) {
                return {y: +d[priceRange]};
              });
          }));
          var myTarget = 10000000;
          chunks.forEach( function (arrayItem)
              {
                var l = 12;
                for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                  myTotal += arrayItem[i].y;
                };
              });
          myTotal = myTotal/myTarget*100;
          deferred.resolve(myTotal);
     });
    return deferred.promise();
    }
```

Is it ever possible to return the value from `GetDataFromJson()` and use it, or will I only ever be able to log it to the console?

**EDIT** after reading through the answer the only way to do this is to call the gauge update function within my GetDataFromJson call - all these promises were seemingly pointless distractions from just passing the right info across:

```
function GetDataFromJson(f) {
      var jsonData;
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
    d3.json("http://localhost:8000/pipeline.json", function(dataFromServer){
          jsonData = dataFromServer;
          if( f == "Current"){ 
            console.log('c');
            headers = ["Won"]
        } else if( f == "Projected"){ 
          console.log('p');
            headers = ["Won", "Prospecting", "Qualifying", "Demonstrating", "Negotiating"]
        }
          else {
            alert('An error has occured')
          };

          myTotal = 0;
          chunks = (headers.map(function(priceRange) {
              return jsonData.map(function(d) {
                return {y: +d[priceRange]};
              });
          }));
          var myTarget = 10000000;
          chunks.forEach( function (arrayItem)
              {
                var l = 12;
                for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                  myTotal += arrayItem[i].y;
                };
              });
          myTotal = myTotal/myTarget*100;
          gauge5.update(myTotal);
          deferred.resolve(myTotal);
     });
    return true;
    }
```

Now I call GetDataFromJson() directly from a click on a radio button, and pass either "Current" or "Projected" inside that call so the right data is shown. Feels stupid that I've wasted a week studying this, but hopefully this answer will help others. You can't extract data from these promises but you can call another function (in my case gauge5.update) and send it the value you want to use.

Comment: You shouldn't put an answer in your question. It's perfectly valid to answer your own question

Comment: I thought I'd mark the answer below as correct as it helped me understand what was going on - then just update the question to show the actual code.

Comment: Which is fine but if you have another answer, you should add an answer. As it stands you have put your answer, in the question. This isn't correct. Questions should only contain questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning 'data' inside callback, not in function NewValue. NewValue should return promise and caller of NewValue should assign a callback on completion of this promise.

```
function NewValue(){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  var dataPromise = GetDataFromJson();
  dataPromise.done(function(data){
  //note both console.log(data) and alert(data) deliver the correct result here
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}

 NewValue()
  .done(function(data){
      // do whatever
   })
```

I am assuming you want to process the data further in NewValue function, else why can't you directly call GetDataFromJson?

Comment: I would be perfectly happy to call it from GetDataFromJson - I was stuck with that and then went down this path of adding promises. Essentially NewValue() should return an integer, which is passes to a d3 function to update a graph. Provided I can get the return to yield an integer value and not "undefined" I'm happy either way,

Comment: Using your code in NewValue() I still get "NaN" returned to the graph - it seems to be some kind of Javascript object that was sent back: Object { state=function(),  always=function(),  then=function(),  more...}

Comment: Please update your call to NewValue. The object you have mentioned looks like promise object, you need assign callback to the 'then' or 'done' functions.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I understand what I need to do. If I call "NewValue()" in the console I get the above output. What should I be calling in order to get the data I need?

Comment: Try this in console: NewValue()
  .done(function(data){
      console.log(data)
   })

Comment: That returns both the promise object and the correct value. Is there any way I can JUST return the value (as a value - not as console.log(value)? I just want the return value to be an integer for graphing purposes.

Comment: NewValue() is an async functions which returns promise syncronously, you need to assign callback to done/then function which NewValue returns

Comment: Sorry - I get that I need to use NewValue().done(function... something ...) - but what is the something that will pull the data from the Promise object? I don't want to log the value to the console - I want to use it in my graph.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on promises and asynchronous function in general. Why can't you call the render function of your graph from this function? May be create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118390/discussion-between-chirag-kothari-and-zoinks10).